# Can I reset the the level of a promoted unit?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

I've just gotten Felicia to level 15 and I'm looking to change her class. Using a Heart Seal will allow me to do just that, but her level is still 15. Is there a way I can reduce her level to 1 so that she can continue to level and gain more experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afraid not.  There's no way to reset levels, as Awakening had it.  Once they gain a level, that's it.  No way back.

What you *can*, do, though is use special seals, Eternal Seals, on them once they've been promoted to their next tier.  Those seals will increase their level cap by 5 each time you use them on a unit.  These cost 12,000 gold from your store, and can only be bought from a level 3 shop an unlimited number of times.  This upgrade only becomes available after Chapter 20, any route.

Comment: Do you know if there is a limit to the number of times a single unit can use Eternal Seals?

Comment: I've heard conflicting information about that.  Some say it's only good for an additional 20 levels, others say you can go right up to level 99.

Comment: @Frank, I realize this is really late but I can confirm that there is not a 20 level cap on Eternal Seals. I do not know what the actual cap is, but I have extremely buffed up my Camilla on Conquest at level 66 and MC in Revelations nearing 70.